# Ruby Gem install failing to find Postgres libraries

Tags: ruby, postgresql, installation, sinatra

I'm going through the instructions for linking Ruby&Sinatra up to Postgres, as found at: 
http://recipes.sinatrarb.com/p/databases/postgresql-datamapper?

The final step of the install is failing, when I attempt to run:

```
gem install dm-postgres-adapter
```

...and the key part of the error message looks to be these lines:

```
checking for -lpq... no
checking for -llibpq... no
```

I've located libpq.dll & libpq.lib on my drive at:

```
D:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\lib
```

After poking around looking for pq.dll or pq.lib, I don't see either of those on the drive.

Comment: Note: The full install went off without a hitch on my other computer (an OSX laptop) but the windows desktop I've been wrestling with since morning.

Comment: I'm on OS X so not sure about the DLL issues but that tutorial seems a bit old :) The datamapper gem is no longer maintained and has been archived on Github. It's been replaced with ROM (Ruby Object Mapper) which is quite complex. If you don't need the datamapper pattern specifically I'd try the sequel gem or activerecord (which can be used with Sinatra independent of Rails).

Comment: @kreek If you want to make that an official answer, to just avoid the DataMapper gem entirely, I'm happy to accept it so you get the credit and this question is there for others to find in the future. I ended up going with the straight "pg" gem and writing raw SQL and now life is good.